# C# EF: joining EF entity class and a static function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, left-join

i try to join my class which represent db table and another class static function which return series of date. my code is working but i am not getting desired value.

the class `MyData` has some missing date and my static function return dates. if the date static function return not found in `MyData` then i want to return zero value for `EAmount field` for that row. if data found in `MyData` for the date which return static function then i will return `EAmount` actual value.

```
[Table("MyData")]
public partial class MyData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EDate { get; set; }

    public decimal? EAmount { get; set; }

    public DateTime? AddDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ModDate { get; set; }
}
```

my requirement something like i left join between two table.

suppose table 1 has date and table 2 has date and amount. join will be based on date. if there is no matching date in table2 for date present in table 1 then i want to show table 1 date and zero as value but if date match then i will take date from table 1 and amount from table 2. this is my simple requirement which i am trying to do by EF joining a EF entity table and a static function.

so here static function will play the role for table1 and EF entity class play role for table2.

here is my full code. code execute but the problem is `EAmount value` is getting always zero.

### full code

```
[Table("MyData")]
public partial class MyData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EDate { get; set; }

    public decimal? EAmount { get; set; }

    public DateTime? AddDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ModDate { get; set; }
}

public class DateRange
{
    public static List<DateTime> GetDates(DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate)
    {
        List<DateTime> dates = Enumerable.Range(0, (enddate - startdate).Days + 1)
            .Select(day => startdate.AddDays(day)).ToList();

        return dates;
    }
}

public partial class LocalDbContext : DbContext
{
    public LocalDbContext()
        : base("name=LocalTest")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<MyData> MyDatas { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

### calling like this way

```
    using (var db = new LocalDbContext())
    {

        var result = from p in DateRange.GetDates(new DateTime(2017, 01, 01), new DateTime(2017, 01, 20))
                     join n in db.MyDatas on p equals n.EDate into g
                     from x in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new
                     {
                         date = p,
                         amount = x == null ? 0 : x.EAmount
                     };

        var xx = result.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is not right because your dates contains time and due to time value join is not working properly. So while implementing join you need to exclude the time part of date and implement the join based on date only. Following is the modified query for you to get proper data:

```
using (var db = new LocalDbContext())
            {

                var result = from p in DateRange.GetDates(new DateTime(2017, 01, 01), new DateTime(2017, 01, 20))
                             join n in db.MyDatas.Where(x => x.EDate != null) on p.Date equals n.EDate.Value.Date into g
                             from x in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             select new
                             {
                                 date = p,
                                 amount = x == null ? 0 : x.EAmount
                             };

                var xx = result.ToList();
            }
```

Comment: tell me why u use where clause. the only difference between your code and my code is where clause and the moment i use where clause like u then code started working. what where clause is doing there.

Comment: no EDate  field in MyDatas table has null value then why you use it ? after adding it code giving right output but reason is not clear to me. please explain the reason in details as a result i can visualize the reason for using where clause and null check. thanks

Comment: I am using where clause because in my query i am using n.EDate.Value.Date to join the tables on date value only without time. As you can see in your entity EDate is a nullable field so if in any case your EDate will be null then my above condition of n.EDate.Value.Date will throw error so to avoid that i am using where condition.  Now for second query- If it is the case that your data will always contain a value in this field then i will suggest you to make it non nullable and then you can remove where clause plus directly use n.EDate.Date instead of n.EDate.Value.Date. Hope this help you.@Mou